# R read data with 0 in front

Tags: r

How can I read data with 0 in front, eg:

```
read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F,text="
a b
1 2
3 04
")
```

I got the second row of 3, 4 instead of 3, 04, what should I do to keep the 0 in front, thanks.

Comment: So you want it to be characters instead of numeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read.table()`'s `colClasses=` argument to let it know that you want to read the columns in as vectors of class `"character"`:

```
read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F,
colClasses="character", 
text="
a b
1 2
3 04
")
#   a  b
# 1 1  2
# 2 3 04
```

(Or, to read your first column as numeric and only the second one as character, set `colClasses=c("numeric", "character")`)